# bug in towers of hanoi code

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

while coding recursive solution  for towers of hanoi, my code works for 1, 2 and 3 discs but not after that.
not able to figure out what am i doing wrong.

```
package recursion;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;

public class Hanoi {

    private static List<Integer> reference = Lists.newArrayList(4, 3, 2, 1);

    private static List<Integer> aList = Lists.newArrayList(reference);
    private static List<Integer> bList = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(aList.size() - 1);
    private static List<Integer> cList = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(aList.size());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        hanoi(aList, bList, cList);
        System.out.println(cList);
        Assert.isTrue(cList.equals(reference));
        Assert.isTrue(aList.size() == 0);
        Assert.isTrue(bList.size() == 0);
        System.out.println("done");

    }

    private static void hanoi(List<Integer> aList, List<Integer> bList, List<Integer> cList) {
        if (aList.size() == 1) {
            cList.add(aList.remove(0));
            return;
        }
        hanoi(aList.subList(1, aList.size()), cList, bList);
        print();
        hanoi(aList.subList(0, 1), null, cList);
        print();
        hanoi(bList, aList, cList);
        print();
        System.out.println("=======================================");
    }

    private static void print() {
        System.out.println(aList);
        System.out.println(bList);
        System.out.println(cList);
        Assert.isTrue(Ordering.natural().reverse().isOrdered(aList));
        Assert.isTrue(Ordering.natural().reverse().isOrdered(bList));
        Assert.isTrue(Ordering.natural().reverse().isOrdered(cList));
        System.out.println("******************************************");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is based on the assumption that towers of hanoi always shifts all slices except one in the first (and last) step.

This is assumption is wrong. Subproblems shift smaller towers.

Add a param size to your hanoi-method. All three steps have to be adjusted:

- Step 1 and 3 should only shift size-1
- Step 2 should not shift the first slice, but the last (the most upper)

Comment: i tried with the N parameter, it works fine. but in my original approach which i used above i  expected that i am passing sublists with N-1 size recursively so should work fine. it works fine till a stage if i see the print statements but then stops. just trying to figure out how can i make the existing code work.

Comment: The problem is: The academic algorithm uses the same shifting size (n-1) for step1 and step3. alist.size -1 (maybe this could work) and blist.size-1 (but this not).

Comment: just for future reference if anyone sees this, the code with param N works fine which i pasted below. not truly the answer i was seeking but might help someone.

private static void hanoiN(List<Integer> aList, List<Integer> bList, List<Integer> cList, int n) {
  if (n == 1) {
   countMoves++;
   cList.add(aList.remove(aList.size() - 1));
   return;
  }
  hanoiN(aList, cList, bList, n - 1);
  print();
  hanoiN(aList, bList, cList, 1);
  print();
  hanoiN(bList, aList, cList, n - 1);
  print();
  System.out.println("=======================================");
 }

Comment: marking above answer as accepted. though i am still not convinced (or able to understand) why my original code does not work though it is designed similar to the approach with parameter N.

Comment: Take the broken algorithm, add the N (but not use it, except for parameter passing). Then compare N with alist.size() at the beginning of the method - it will fail at some time. If you debug you will find that step 3 passes in list b with other size than a, which breaks the assumption.